java project images and connected texts are not showing
In my java project related images are not showing along with texts beside them also

and the path is this 
here is my block code of the side button class,
import Model.Database;
import Model.user;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SideButton extends JPanel {

    public SideButton(String text, String pic, user user, Database database, JFrame f) {
        super(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 10));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(182, 50));
        setBackground(GUIConstants.white);
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

        // Corrected resource path
        //String resourcePath = "/application_socialmedia/pics/" + pic + ".png";
        // Corrected resource path
        //String resourcePath = "/resources/application_socialmedia/pics/" + pic + ".png";
        //String resourcePath1 = "/resources/application_socialmedia/pics/" + pic + ".png";
        String resourcePath2 = "/resources/application_socialmedia/pics/" + pic + ".png";
        
        
        System.out.println("Expected resource path: " + resourcePath2);

        // Loading image using getResource()
        URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(resourcePath2);
        System.out.println("Trying to load image using getResource(): " + imgURL);

        // Loading image using ClassLoader
        InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/application_socialmedia/pics/" + pic + ".png");
        System.out.println("Trying to load image using ClassLoader: " + stream);

        if (imgURL != null) {
            JLabel img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imgURL));
            add(img);
        } else if (stream != null) {
            try {
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(stream));
                JLabel img = new JLabel(icon);
                add(img);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Unable to read image from InputStream!");
                e.printStackTrace();
                add(new JLabel("Image not found"));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Image not found at path: " + resourcePath2);
            JLabel img = new JLabel("Image not found");
            add(img);
        }

        // Add text label
        add(new JLabel(text));

        // Mouse listener
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                new CustomView(text, user, database);
                f.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                setBackground(GUIConstants.hover);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                setBackground(GUIConstants.white);
            }
        });
    }
}


and the other class for this is home one it is here,
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package View;

import Controller.CreatePost;
import Controller.GenerateTimeline;
import Model.Database;
import Model.user;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import static java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Home {
    
    public Home(user user, Database database){
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       
       
       //new GenerateTimeline(user, database);
       
        JPanel sideBar = new JPanel();
        sideBar.setBackground(GUIConstants.white);
        Dimension sideBarDim = new Dimension(182, 1000);
        sideBar.setPreferredSize(sideBarDim);
        sideBar.setMaximumSize(sideBarDim);
        //sideBar.setMaximumSize(sideBarDim);
        sideBar.setLayout(new BoxLayout(sideBar, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        sideBar.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(3));
        
        
        JPanel profile = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
        //frame.getContentPane().add(sideBar, BorderLayout.WEST);
        
        //JPanel profile = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
        profile.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(182, 50));
        profile.setBackground(GUIConstants.white);
        profile.setCursor(new Cursor(HAND_CURSOR));
        profile.add(new JLabel(user.getName(), 19, GUIConstants.black, Font.BOLD));
        
        
        profile.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
           @Override
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               new Modify(user, database);
               frame.dispose();
           }

           @Override
           public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
               
           }

           @Override
           public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
               
           }

           @Override
           public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
               
           }

           @Override
           public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
               
           }
       });
        
        
        sideBar.add(profile);
        
        sideBar.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(3));
        
        sideBar.add(new SideButton("Posts", "save", user, database, frame));
        
        sideBar.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(3));
        sideBar.add(new SideButton("Comments", "comment", user, database, frame));
        
        sideBar.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(3));
        sideBar.add(new SideButton("Likes", "like", user, database, frame));
        
        sideBar.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(3));
        sideBar.add(new SideButton("Friends", "friends", user, database, frame));
        /*
         sideBar.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(3));
         frame.getContentPane().add(sideBar, BorderLayout.WEST);
         
         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
         panel.setBackground(null);
         
         JPanel header = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
         header.setBackground(GUIConstants.white);
         Dimension dimension = new Dimension(500, 159);
         header.setPreferredSize(dimension);
         header.setMinimumSize(dimension);
         header.setMaximumSize(dimension);
         header.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 15, 10, 15));
         
         
         
         JPanel north = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
         north.setBackground(null);
         north.add(new JLabel("Home", 20, GUIConstants.black, Font.BOLD),BorderLayout.WEST);
         header.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
         
         */
         
         
        //frame.getContentPane().add(sideBar, BorderLayout.WEST);
       
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setBackground(null);
        
        JPanel header = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        header.setBackground(GUIConstants.white);
        Dimension demension = new Dimension(500, 159);
        header.setPreferredSize(demension);
        header.setMinimumSize(demension);
        header.setMaximumSize(demension);
        header.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 15, 10, 15));
        
        JPanel north = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        north.setBackground(null);
        north.add(new JLabel("Home", 20, GUIConstants.black, Font.BOLD), BorderLayout.WEST);
        header.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        JTextArea postIn = new JTextArea("Share your thoughts....", 18, 20);
        header.add(new JScrollPane(postIn), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JPanel south = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        south.setBackground(null);
        
        JButton postBtn = new JButton("Post", 35, 16);
        postBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
           @Override
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(postIn. isEmpty()){
                   new Alert("Cannot publish empty post", frame);
                   return;
                }
                
                Model.post post = new Model.post(postIn.getText(), user);
                  if(new CreatePost(post, database).posted()){
                     new Alert("Posted Successfully", frame);
                     postIn.setText("");
                  }
           }

           @Override
           public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
               
           }

           @Override
           public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
               
           }

           @Override
           public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
               
           }

           @Override
           public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
               
           }
       });
        
       
        postBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(81, 37));
        south.add(postBtn);
        header.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        panel.add(header);
        //panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(7));
        //panel.add(new Post());
        
        /*
        ArrayList<Model.post> posts = new GenerateTimeline(user, database).getPosts();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(7));
            panel.add(new Post(posts.get(i)));
        }*/
        
        ArrayList<Model.post> posts = new GenerateTimeline(user, database).getPosts();
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(posts.size(), 10); i++) {
                panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(7));
                panel.add(new Post(user, posts.get(i), database, frame));
}

        //JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
       // scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
        
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(panel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(182), BorderLayout.EAST);
         //scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
        
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.requestFocus();
       
    }
    
}


can someone please tell me how to fix images and along texts are not showing ,
I changed the folder path several ways but it is not showing.  I expected to appers that images with the text along with them . I using the apache netbeans and along with php my admin database.

Are you using an IDE? You need to include the images in a folder on your classpath. Then when you getResource it will be relative to the folder on the classpath. Eg. if the resources folder is on your class path, then you would use the path after that. eg "/application_socialmedia/pics/"

It looks like your "application_socialmedia" is a folder in your source. It isn't clear that netbeans will package that with your application when you run it. Plus your images are in a folder called "pics" inside of your sources folder. So the path should probably be "/pics/comments.png"

As u said I changed code as but it still didn't fixed. I fixed both but it isn't

Are you the print statements saying? Also you should show the most recent code you see and any output your getting. You have some print statements that could help you debug.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Trying to load image using getResource(): null
Expected resource path: /Application_SocialMedia/pics/save.png
Trying to load image using ClassLoader: null
Error: Image not found at path: /Application_SocialMedia/pics/save.png
Trying to load image using getResource(): null  this is the output it shows

According to the image in your question, there needs to be a folder pics whose parent folder is the same parent folder as View where that View folder contains file SideButton.class, i.e. the file created when you compile SideButton.java and I suggest using the following code – probably in the constructor of class SideButton – to create an icon.
java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("/pics/" + pic); // assuming value of [parameter] 'pic' is, for example, 'comment.png'
java.awt.image.BufferedImage bi = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(url);
javax.swing.ImageIcon icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(bi);
JLabel img = new JLabel(icon);

Note that it doesn't matter how you compile your Java project, just make sure, after the compilation, that the PNG files are in the pics directory and that the parent directory of the pics directory is the same parent as the View directory that contains file SideButton.class.
Note that I am assuming that you are not packaging your Java project into a JAR file.
If the above does not resolve your problem, consider editing your question and posting a minimal, reproducible example.
